# Lambda expression. Get the first result by date, for each person

Tags: asp.net, list, lambda

i have `list<result>` of result objects with these properties {`person`, `score`, `regdate`}. And i want to only select the first registered score from each person (so i get 1 result for each person, even if the person have more results).

I need this so i can use them to make an average score for first time results.

Answer (score 0):

If your initial list of results is:

```
List<Result> results=...
```

Then you can do this:

```
var scores = results
                    .GroupBy(r => r.person.Id)
                    .Select(g => g
                                  .OrderBy(res=>res.regdate)
                                  .First()
                            );
```

Comment: This didnt work for me, but i found a sulotion that did.


var firstResults = result
                .GroupBy(x => x.Person)
                .Select(g => g.Aggregate((r1, r2) => r1.regDate < r2.regDate ? r1 : r2))
                .ToList();